# как сравнить две даты в JavaScript с помощью moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Для упрощенной работы с временем я воспользовалсь библиотекой moment.js.
Мне необходимо производить проверку даты и времени задачи, что бы конец задачи, не был раньше чем начало, или не был одинаковым.

Из формы я получаю данные с временем, следующим дедовским способом

```
var start = $('#start').val()
var end = $('#end').val()
```

В результате получаю строку следующего формата

```
15-04-2017 19:02:06
```

Как мне сравнить эти значения по заданным условиям, с помощью moment.js? Я не совсем четко поняла как делается это по документации...

Answer (score 2):

Прочитать [документацию](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)?

```
const start = $('#start').val()
const end = $('#end').val()
const firstDate = moment(start)
const secondDate = moment(end)

firstDate.isSameOrBefore(secondDate)
```

Comment: я правильно поняла что для проверки по моим условиям мне нужно использовать .isSameOrBefore()?

Comment: @ElectroGirl, да